# Get decode array that turns black into specific color

Tags: color, backgrounds

I have chosen a specific color that I am using for my letters. The color is used in headings and titles. I also have a black and white image that I want to use as a background, but I want it to have my chosen color instead of black. Is there a simple way to do this, without tweaking the parameters by hand?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.78in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\colorlet{MyColor1}{RoyalPurple}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{{\color{MyColor1} \textsc{\Huge{My Name} \\[-1.5pt] \Large{some tagline}}\\ \Large{\vspace{-8.5pt}} \HRule}}
\footskip = 0pt
\cfoot{\newcommand{\NL}{ $\ast$ }
{\color{MyColor1} \HRule \textsc{\footnotesize{\\ My address} \footnotesize{ \\ my.email@server.com \NL webpage.com \\ +44 123 456 789}}}}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[decodearray={MyColor1}, width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}}, angle=0, position=current page.south, anchor=above, vshift=10pt}


\begin{document}
{\color{MyColor1}\Huge Title}\\[1cm]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting file]

Comment: Option `decodearray` will not help, because it does not allow to change the color model, i.e., it does not convert gray images to  the RGB color model. The [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) explains the feature and the syntax of the value for `decodearray`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek , Well `decodearray={0.38 1 0.25 1 0.6 1}` turns the black in my figure into the purple color I want. I'm just looking for an automatic way of doing it.

Comment: Then, the image is *not* a "black and white" image with the color model "gray".

Answer (score 3):

You can play with the blend modes offered by Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.78in, left=1in, right=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\colorlet{MyColor1}{RoyalPurple}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{{\color{MyColor1} \textsc{\Huge{My Name} \\[-1.5pt] \Large{some tagline}}\\ \Large{\vspace{-8.5pt}} \HRule}}
\footskip = 0pt
\cfoot{\newcommand{\NL}{ $\ast$ }
{\color{MyColor1} \HRule \textsc{\footnotesize{\\ My address} \footnotesize{ \\ my.email@server.com \NL webpage.com \\ +44 123 456 789}}}}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\tikz[blend mode=screen]{\node (img){%
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\fill[MyColor1](img.south east) rectangle (img.north west);}},%
 angle=0, position=current page.south, anchor=above, vshift=10pt}


\begin{document}
{\color{MyColor1}\Huge Title}\\[1cm]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks! I just copied it from the OP's code, not knowing what it does, and you're right I've should have looked it up.

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, this puts a rectangle with my color on top of the other image and blends them together. If so, it will not solve my problem as my image isn't rectangular and it has white parts in the middle.

Comment: @Kajsa You can fill all sorts of shapes with Ti*k*Z. I was just working with what you had in your MWE.

Answer (score 3):

Package `xcolor` provides useful macros for extracting and converting color specifications.
The following example uses them to convert the color into the color model `rgb`.
The values are parsed to construct the `decodearray`.

Requirement:

- The image must be a bitmap image in the RGB color space.

The image is generated with the following TeX code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{1mm}
  \fbox{\sffamily\bfseries ABC}
\end{document}
```

It is converted via Ghostscript and the device `pngalpha` to `abc.png`:

> [image: Image, black and white, RGB colors, bitmap]

Now the document that includes the image:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{MyColor1}{RoyalPurple}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ParseColorToRgbDecodeArray}[2]{%
  \extractcolorspecs{#1}\ParseResultModel\ParseResultColor
  \convertcolorspec\ParseResultModel\ParseResultColor{rgb}\ParseRgb
  \let#2\@empty
  \@for\ParseValue:=\ParseRgb\do{%
    \edef#2{%
      #2%
      \ifx#2\@empty
      \else
        \space
      \fi
      \ParseValue\space 1%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\ParseColorToRgbDecodeArray{MyColor1}\MyColorOneDecodeArray

\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[decodearray={\MyColorOneDecodeArray}]{abc.png}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with image and decodearray]

**Caveat:**

The original color was given as CMYK color. The image uses RGB. Therefore, the colors in the different models can be displayed differently.

Comment: Very helpful, though the color doesn't come out quite right, might be do to the conversion. What should I remove to get the CMYK version of the code?

Comment: Actually, the CMYK code doesn't come out right either.

Comment: @Kajsa PNG does not support CMYK.

Comment: I meant the decode array. The numbers for that aren't the correct ones for the color. RoyalPurple has the RGB code {0.38 0.25 0.6}, but the numbers that I get from this are {0.25 0.1 1}, excluding the 1's for the white.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for. Had to convert a svg style signature in black to blue and this trick worked like a charm. Thanks again.